# How to fix "AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main, kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException"? error when trying to delete the stored data Sqlite db

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I am trying to develop a Notes application where I can save list of notes. These notes will be saved in SQLite DataBase. I have set a button to delete the created note. When I click on this butting during run time (no complete time error) it is giving me a mentioned error. Kindly help in resolving this issue.

I tried to develop this app by reading and copying the code from

https://github.com/hussien89aa/KotlinUdemy/tree/master/Android/NoteApp/StartUp

```
inner class MyNotesAdapter : BaseAdapter {

    var listNotesAdapter = ArrayList<note>()
    var context: Context? = null

    constructor(listNotesAdapter: ArrayList<note>) : super() {
        this.listNotesAdapter = listNotesAdapter
        this.context = context
    }


    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        var myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ticket, null)
        var myNote = listNotesAdapter[position]
        myView.tvTitle.text = myNote.nodeName
        myView.tvDes.text = myNote.nodeDes


        myView.delete.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

            var dbManager = DbManager(this.context!!) //This is the line where I am getting error.

            val selectionArgs = arrayOf(myNote.nodeID.toString())
            dbManager.Delete("ID=?", selectionArgs)
            LoadQuery("%")
        })
```

Comment: @EpicPandaForce could you please reopen the question, because the answers from the linked one about NullPointerException in Java are not much relevant to Kotlin and its KotlinNullPointerException that happens when `!!` operator encounters `null` value. It would also be nice to explain why `context` is null here.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `KotlinNullPointerException` here because of the failed null assertion in the expression `context!!` in that line: `!!` operator ensures that the expression to the left is not null or throws `KNPE` otherwise.

Here `context` variable is null by the time it has been accessed in the `OnClickListener`. By why is it null? I suppose because it was never assigned to something other than null in this code example. In particular, the following part of code looks suspicious:

```
inner class MyNotesAdapter : BaseAdapter {
    ...
    var context: Context? = null

    constructor(listNotesAdapter: ArrayList<note>) : super() {
        ...
        this.context = context
    }
```

Here you assign the value of `context` to the `context` variable, but where does that value come from? The closest identifier with this name is the same `context` variable, which is initially null, so this variable gets `null` assigned once again.

In fact, IDE even reports `Variable 'context' is assigned to itself` warning on this line.